# Scrapy - How can I obtain the 'src' value for a 'script' tag

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to obtain the 'src' values for 'script' tags using Scrapy (http://scrapy.org/).

I can do this no problem for images:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//img'):
    item = elSRC()
    item['src'] = sel.xpath('@src').extract()
    yield item
```

Sample output:

```
{"src": ["http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51UBHVgfefL._AC_SX75_.jpg"]},
```

However, the same thing for a script tag doesn't seem to work:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//script'):
        item = elSRC()
        item['src'] = sel.xpath('@src').extract()
        yield item
```

Sample output:

```
{"src": []},
```

I confirmed manually that the script tags on the page in question did indeed have 'src' values present.  I've also tried a number of other approaches utilizing the Scrapy shell to no avail.

Has anyone else been able to obtain the 'src' values for a 'script' tag using Scrapy, and if so how did you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: try printing `sel.extract()` to check how scrapy sees the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Uggg.  In the horribly formatted page I was looking at the 'src' appeared to be populated.  Paul Trmbrth's comment prompted me to examine things again and setup a much simpler test page to validate my findings.  I believe this is solved.  Moral of the story:  Utilize clean, easy to read code to testing purposes, and set up simple environments before you tackle complex production items.